# Runtime error when deleting a row in Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     MsgBox Target.Value 
End Sub
```

After I enter text to some cell I get a message box, but if I try to delete the row where I just entered a text, I get an error:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

How can I fix this error? Why the condition doesn't catch it?

Comment: Sorry, missed the important part MsgBox Target.Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete row as a result the whole row is `target` object in your procedure. Therefore your macro is not able to return value of the row.

What programmers usually do is additional condition which is checked before your message box:

```
If Target.Count =1 Then
    'your messagebox here
End If
```

Comment: @Tyrick, in fact the condition is the same to this one `If Target.Cells.Count = 1` which means that we check how many cells are affected with the change. if only one we trigger action and reject all the other situation when user changes/delets more cells at a time.